# Compare a column has duplicate cells and then compare duplicate cells again on corresponding column

Tags: excel-formula

I want to find the duplicate cells in Item Name.  For example A is duplicated. And then compare the duplicate content from Item Name A.  Therefore, row 2 and row 6 are duplicated.  How to setup the equation to determine the duplication?

```
1 Item Name Content Dupicate?
2 A         Mary    Y
3 B         Peter   N
4 C         John    N
5 A         Mary    Y
6 B         Paul    N
7 A         Peter   N
```

Answer (score 0):

If Items are in ColumnB and Names in ColumnC I think a suitable formula might be:

> =IF(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,C2,$B$2:$B$7,B2)>1,"Y","N")